# Can I use Mac keybindings in insert mode?

Tags: key-bindings, macos

I use Vim on a Mac book, and I am wondering if it is possible for me to use Mac keybindings when I am in `insert` mode.

For example, <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd> to remove the word before the cursor, <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> to go to the beginning of a line, etc.

Thanks in advance!